# Duplicate nodes when removing from kdtree

Tags: c, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am writing an algorithm that requires me to search nearest neighbors of points. I found the kdtree library from this post ([Using Google's C KD Tree Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205971/using-googles-c-kd-tree-library)) but it does not have a function to delete individual nodes from the tree. So I started to implement my own using 
**www (dot) geeksforgeeks.org/k-dimensional-tree-set-3-delete/** 
as a template. It all runs through but unfortunately sometimes nodes get duplicated. 
My test case is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "kdtree.h"

/* (hopefully) platform independent directory creation */
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)   /* this should be defined under windows, regardless of 64 or 32 bit*/
#include <direct.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define GetWorkingDir _getcwd
#define MakeDir(str) _mkdir(str)
#else                                   /* unix based system */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define GetWorkingDir getcwd
#define MakeDir(str) mkdir(str, 0777)
#endif

#ifndef MAX_PATH
#define MAX_PATH 260
#endif

void GetLogDir(char* strPath, int nBufSize)
{
    if(GetWorkingDir(strPath, nBufSize))
    {
        strncat(strPath, "/log/", 5);
        MakeDir(strPath);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get working directory");
        exit(ENOENT);
    }
}

FILE* GetOpenFileHandle(const char* strFilenamePlusPath, const char* strOpenMode)
{
    if(strOpenMode == NULL)     // too bad we dont have default arguments in C :(
    {
            strOpenMode = "a+";
    }

    return(fopen(strFilenamePlusPath, strOpenMode));
}

int CloseFile(FILE* pFile)
{
    if(pFile != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(pFile, "\r\n"); // append a new line before closing!
        return(fclose(pFile));
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid file handle");
    exit(EFAULT);
}


void NodeLabelToFile(FILE* pFile, kdnode* node, const char* strName)
{
    fprintf(pFile, "%s [label=\"(%.3f, %.3f)\"] \n", strName, node->pos[0], node->pos[1]);
}

char* NodeToString(kdnode* node, int* num)
{
    char* strName = (char*) malloc(MAX_PATH);
    if(*num == 0)
    {
        sprintf(strName, "%s","root");
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(strName, "node%d", *num);
    }
    return strName;
}


void NodesToFile(FILE* pFile, kdnode* node, const char* strParentname, int* num)
{
    if(node && pFile)
    {
        char* strLeft = NULL;
        char* strRight = NULL;

        if(node->left)
        {
            (*num)++;
            strLeft = NodeToString(node->left, num);
            NodeLabelToFile(pFile, node->left, strLeft);
            fprintf(pFile, "%s -> %s \n", strParentname, strLeft);
        }

        if(node->right)
        {
            (*num)++;
            strRight = NodeToString(node->right, num); // name of the current node
            NodeLabelToFile(pFile, node->right, strRight);
            fprintf(pFile, "%s -> %s \n", strParentname, strRight);
        }

        if(strLeft)
        {
            NodesToFile(pFile, node->left, strLeft, num);
            free(strLeft);
        }
        if(strRight)
        {
            // (*num)++;
            NodesToFile(pFile, node->right, strRight, num);
            free(strRight);
        }
    }
}


FILE* MakeOpenLogFile(const char* strFilename, const char* strOpenMode)
{
    if(strOpenMode == NULL)
    {
        strOpenMode = "a+";
    }

    char* strFilenamePlusPath = (char*) malloc(MAX_PATH);
    GetLogDir(strFilenamePlusPath, MAX_PATH);
    strncat(strFilenamePlusPath, strFilename, strlen(strFilename));
    FILE* pFile = GetOpenFileHandle(strFilenamePlusPath, strOpenMode);
    free(strFilenamePlusPath);
    return(pFile);
}

void KDTreeToDotFile(kdtree* Tree, const char* strFilename)
{
    if(Tree)
    {
        FILE* pFile = MakeOpenLogFile(strFilename, "w");

        fprintf(pFile, "%s", "digraph d { \n"); // print opening statement for the graph in dot language

        // traverse the tree and print the nodes
        int* num = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));  // make this a unique location to make sure numbers can't occur twice

        *num = 0;
        char* strRoot = NodeToString(Tree->root, num);
        NodeLabelToFile(pFile, Tree->root, strRoot);
        NodesToFile(pFile, Tree->root, "root", num);

        if(strRoot)
        {
            free(strRoot);
        }
        free(num);
        fprintf(pFile,"%s", "}");            // close the digraph environment
        CloseFile(pFile);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int numel = 20;
    int toRemove = 19;
    double dMax = 3000;
    int nNumDim = 2;

    printf("init rng");
    srand(1234); // seed the rng // srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    printf("creating kdtree");
    kdtree* TreeRoot = kd_create(nNumDim);  // construct the kd tree for the nearest neighbor search
    kd_data_destructor(TreeRoot, free); // set free as data destructor

    double* pos = (double*) malloc(nNumDim * numel * sizeof(double));
    int retval;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < numel; ii++)
    {
        pos[nNumDim * ii] = floor((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/dMax));
        pos[nNumDim * ii + 1] = floor((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/dMax));
        int* randint = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *randint = rand();
        retval = kd_insert2(TreeRoot,
                            pos[nNumDim * ii],
                            pos[nNumDim * ii + 1],
                            randint, sizeof(int));
        assert(retval == 0);
    }

    KDTreeToDotFile(TreeRoot, "original.dot");
    double* dRemovePos = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*nNumDim);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < toRemove; ii++)
    {
        dRemovePos[0] = pos[2*ii];
        dRemovePos[1] = pos[2*ii + 1];
        kd_remove(TreeRoot, dRemovePos);
    }
    KDTreeToDotFile(TreeRoot, "removed.dot");

    kd_free(TreeRoot);                  // free kdtree
    return 0;
}
```

and the functions to remove the nodes are implemented like this:
(I don't think if it is too much code, so I only will post my changes to the kd library. If I should add the rest of the code, which is more than 1000 lines unfortunately, just tell me in the comments.)

```
int kd_remove(kdtree* tree, const double* pos)
{
    printf("removing node %.3f, %.3f \n", pos[0], pos[1]);
    if(tree->root != NULL)
    {
        assert(tree->dim != 0); // prevent division by 0 (error code 136)
        assert(pos != NULL);    // make sure a valid position is passed
        tree->root = remove_rec(tree->root, pos, tree->dim, tree->destr, 0);
    }
    return(0);
}

kdnode* remove_rec(kdnode* node, const double* pos, int dim, void (*destr)(void*), int depth)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return(NULL);
    }

    int curdim = depth % dim;

    if(same_pos(node->pos, pos, dim))
    {
        // we found the droid we're looking for
        if(node->right)
        {
            // find the minimum in the right subtree
            kdnode* node_min = find_min(node->right, curdim, dim);
            if(node_min)
            {
                copy_node_data(node_min, node, dim);
                node->right = remove_rec(node->right, node_min->pos, dim, destr, depth + 1);
            }
        }
        else if(node->left)
        {
            // find the minimum in the left subtree
            kdnode* node_min = find_min(node->left, curdim, dim);
            if(node_min)
            {
                copy_node_data(node_min, node, dim);
                node->left = remove_rec(node->left, node_min->pos, dim, destr, depth + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // no subtrees -> delete the found node
            clear_rec(node, destr);
            return(NULL);
        }
        return node;    // return the newly filled node to the recursion step one "above"
    }
    else
    {
        // points are not the same, look further
        if(pos[curdim] < node->pos[curdim])
        {
            // position we're looking for is smaller -> go left
            node->left = remove_rec(node->left, pos, dim, destr, depth + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // go right, position we're looking for is greater
            node->right = remove_rec(node->right, pos, dim, destr, depth + 1);
        }
        return node;
    }
}

void copy_node_data(const kdnode* src, kdnode* dst, int dim)
{
    if(src && dst)
    {
        int nNumBytes = dim * sizeof(double);
        memcpy(dst->pos, src->pos, nNumBytes);

        if(dst->data != NULL)
        {
            free(dst->data);
            dst->data = malloc(src->databytes);
        }

        memcpy(dst->data, src->data, src->databytes);
        dst->databytes = src->databytes;
    }
}

int same_pos(const double* pos1, const double* pos2, int dim)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
    {
        if(pos1[i] != pos2[i])
        {
            return 0; // false
        }
    }
    return 1;   // true
}

kdnode* find_min(kdnode* node, int dir, int numdim)
{
    return find_min_rec(node, dir, 0, numdim);
}

kdnode* find_min_rec(kdnode* node, int dir, int depth, int numdim)
{
    if(!node)
    { 
        return NULL;
    }

    if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
    {
        return node; // is leaf node 
    }
    int curdim = depth % numdim;
    if(curdim == numdim)
    {
        if(node->left == NULL)
        {
            // no smaller node in tree
            return node;
        }
        else 
        {
            // left subtree is populated -> we need to go deeper
            return find_min_rec(node->left, node->dir, depth + 1, numdim);;
        }
    } 

    // we have to search both subtrees and find the smallest value compared to the current node
    return min_node(node,   find_min_rec(node->left, node->dir, depth + 1, numdim),
                            find_min_rec(node->right, node->dir, depth + 1, numdim), node->dir);
}

kdnode* min_node(kdnode* a, kdnode* left, kdnode* right, int dir)
{
    if(a == NULL)
    {
        // node a is the only one that can't be NULL!
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid node passed! \n");
        exit(EFAULT);
    } 

    kdnode* result = a;

    if(left != NULL)
    {
        if(left->pos[dir] < result->pos[dir])
        {   
            result = left;
        }
    }

    if(right != NULL)
    {
        if(right->pos[dir] < result->pos[dir])
        {
            result = right;
        }
    }  

    return result;
}
```

[original.dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxGu7.png) looks like this and [removed.dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/for8d.png) like that.
I've been debugging this since yesterday and I have the feeling it is something really obvious that I am missing here... 
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help :)

Comment: `pos[nNumDim * ii + 1]` : this looks like an off-by-one to me.

Comment: pos is an `(nNumDim*numel)` sized array, so this should be fine. The position is 2D. I will edit the second for loop, where I just used `2` instead of `nNumDim`

Comment: You are right. Only for (numdim==1) it could cause problems.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I created a minimal test case which I put in my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k2av0x4p6hfox2/kdtree_noderemoval_mwe.zip?dl=0

Comment: Great!  Could you update your question to include this code directly?  (Generally we don't want people to have to follow links / download random things in order to recreate your issue.)

Comment: sure, sorry about that...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError in recursion step n, if the points are not the same and the node is a leaf node then it is returned to the recursion step n-1 and nothing happens. Shouldn't it be that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I know this probably won't be read by anyone but I found the bug after not touching the code for a while and for completeness here is how:

In the `find_min()` function I start the recursion with `depth = 0`. 
This can cause the split dimension to get messed up and therefore not access all the nodes. 
I modified the function to take `depth` as an argument and pass the recursion depth of `remove_rec()` like this:

```
kdnode* node_min = find_min(node->right, curdim, dim, depth + 1);
```

and

```
kdnode* node_min = find_min(node->left, curdim, dim, depth + 1);
```

respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `40` elements

```
int numel = 20;
int nNumDim = 2;

double* pos = (double*) malloc(nNumDim * numel * sizeof(double)); // Don't cast
```

but removing only `38`

```
int toRemove = 19;

for (int ii = 0; ii < toRemove; ii++)
{
    dRemovePos[0] = pos[nNumDim * ii];
    dRemovePos[1] = pos[nNumDim * ii + 1];
    kd_remove(TreeRoot, dRemovePos);
}
```

In the last iteration:

`pos[nNumDim * ii];` = `pos[2 * 18];` = `pos[36];`

`pos[nNumDim * ii + 1];` = `pos[2 * 18 + 1];` = `pos[37];`

`pos[38]` and  `pos[39]` are still there.

Change to `int toRemove = 20;`.

---

Your code is obfuscated due to the flat array, why don't you declare some type like

```
struct data {
    double el1;
    double el2;
};
```

or

```
typedef double data[2];
```

and then

```
data *value = malloc(numel * sizeof(*value));
```

Comment: Hi, yes that is exactly what I want to do. I need to leave one node in the tree to be able to look at the graph that I create (the .dot file). The problem is that nodes are duplicated. I still have 14 nodes in the tree after removing 19 of 20.